# Erlang messages when there are lots of nodes or binary data

Tags: erlang, elixir, erlang-otp

Would native Erlang messages provide **reasonable performance** when there are **lots of nodes or binary data**?

Case 1: There's a **dynamic pool of about 50-200 machines** (erlang nodes). It's constantly changing, about 5-50 machines added or removed every 10min.

Case 2: Let's say we are using this cluster to build youtube-clone and planning to **stream video data via messages**.

By reasonable performance I mean - **it's ok to be 2-3 times slower** than the top possible performance achieved by the complex Erlang code, **10 times slower is not ok**.

Answer (score 2):

There is not any significant difference between sending a message and binary data. The message is just transformed to the binary packet using `term_to_binary` and sent via TCP and same apply to the binary data. (Well, it is little bit smarter than that because textual form of the same atoms is not sent again and again as would simple `term_to_binary` do.) So the difference is negligible.

Answer (score 1):

There are important details:

1) In clusters over 100 nodes, ping noise in full connected cluster will be significant part of network traffic. Even bigger deployments require deep changes in Erlang VM and OS.

2) If you want to stream video or audio you need plan capacity of single node: clients per node, tcp/udp packets rate, network bandwidth.

3) There is performance limit ~150-200K/s messages between 2 processes on different nodes.